# Error: not in scope. Why this is happening?

Tags: haskell

i need to define an *instance* for the class *Enum* based on the datatype *Int'*. I just need to define the functions *toEnum* and *fromEnum*. 
For example: map fromEnum [Minus One .. Plus (Succ’ One)]  ->  [-1,0,1,2]

```
data PosNat = One | Succ' PosNat 
data Int' = Zero' | Plus PosNat | Minus PosNat 

 instance Enum Int' where
  toEnum 0 = Zero'
  toEnum n | n>0 = Plus (toPosNat n )
  toEnum n | n<0 = undefined -- Minus (toPosNat n) 
    where
      toPosNat :: a -> PosNat
      toPosNat 1 = One 
      toPosNat n | n>1 = (Succ' (toPosNat (n-1)) )
      toPosNat n | n<1 = (Succ' (toPosNat (n+1)) )
```

The problem is, i get following error:

```
Variable not in scope: toPosNat :: Int -> PosNat
   |
62 |   toEnum n | n>0 = Plus (toPosNat n )
   |
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Don't repeat function names when you carry on with the guards. So just remove `toEnum n`  in it's third appearance. Also same with `toPostNat n`  in the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to promote `toPosNat` to a top-level function, like this:

```
 instance Enum Int' where
  toEnum 0 = Zero'
  toEnum n | n>0 = Plus (toPosNat n )
  toEnum n | n<0 = undefined -- Minus (toPosNat n) 

 toPosNat :: a -> PosNat
 toPosNat 1 = One 
 toPosNat n | n>1 = (Succ' (toPosNat (n-1)) )
 toPosNat n | n<1 = (Succ' (toPosNat (n+1)) )
```

The `where` clause that you have in your code is only visible in the third case, not in the second case.

Answer (score 4):

A `where` clause attaches to all of the guards of a single pattern. You've defined your function using three separate patterns, so the `where` clause only attaches to the last of them. To fix this, simply roll the last two patterns (which are the same, minus the guards) together:

```
 instance Enum Int' where
   toEnum 0 = Zero'
   toEnum n | n>0 = Plus (toPosNat n )
            | n<0 = Minus (toPosNat n) 
     where
       toPosNat :: a -> PosNat
       toPosNat 1 = One 
       toPosNat n | n>1 = (Succ' (toPosNat (n-1)))
                  | n<1 = (Succ' (toPosNat (n+1)))
```

I've made the same change to `toPosNat` because this is better style, but it has no semantic impact in this case.